# How to move the bootstrap button to left side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my bootstrap code

```
    <div class="input-append" align="center">
    <input type="text" name="q" class="span2 search-query" placeholder="Snipp or Tag"
    />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary active"><i class="icon-white icon-plus"></i> plus</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary active"><i class="icon-white icon-bullhorn"></i> Goto</button>
</div>
```

And here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AsYnY/4/) 
How give top-padding and how to give some space in between the buttons and move the plus and goto button to right side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add another div for those 2 buttons and give `float:right`

And for gap between them give `margin`

```
button{margin-right:6px}
```

[**DEMO UPDATED**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsYnY/7/)

Comment: @jade in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AsYnY/4/ buttons are in the right side of the search only right?

Comment: ya but i wanted it to be on the right most side of the screen, the plus and goto button.Sorry i had it wrong in the question.I just updated my question

Answer (score 5):

if you want to float right you use the built in class "pull-right"

```
<div class="pull-right">...</div>
```

and for search more looking one will be

```
<form class="form-search">
    <div class="input-append" >
    <input type="text" class="span2 search-query input-large" placeholder="search posts,users..">
    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
```

and for keeping distance you can use margin

```
margin:10px
```